# Issue with JAVA pop function in my Stack class

Tags: java, stack

Hi i have a problem with my stack implementation(Java).
This is my code :

```
public class Stack {
char[] stack;
int size;
public Stack(int n) {
    stack = new char[n];
    size = 0;
}
public void push(char c) {
    stack[size] = c;
    size++;
}
public char pop() {
    return stack[size--];
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (size == 0);
}
public void print() {
    System.out.print("Stack : ");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(stack[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

}
this is main method :

```
Stack st = new Stack(4);
    st.push('a');
    st.push('n');
    st.push('a');
    st.print();
    char c = st.pop();
    System.out.println("char : " + c); // here is nothing
```

I think the pop function is wrong because if i call it from main method function return nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, definitely sounds like something is wrong. You should probably check that out and give us a detailed overview of what happens under what conditions.

Comment: Can't really do much with that, need to see how you actually use your stack class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are decrementing `size` twice in `pop` -- once in your debugging print statement, and once when accessing your array.

Because your `size` variable is meant to be one larger than the last valid index, decrement it only once, before you access the array.

```
public char pop() {
    size--;
    System.out.println("class stack : " + stack[size]);
    return stack[size];
}
```